# How pass data to page.eveluate function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, phantomjs, phantomjs-node

Consider code from [node-phantom](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node):

```
page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML;
}).then(function(html){
    console.log(html);
});
```

The funciton is executed directly in html page, so adding a parameter like that:

```
someExternalVariable = 'foo';
page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.getElementById(someExternalVariable).innerHTML;
}).then(function(html){
    console.log(html);
});
```

Leads to undefined `someExternalVariable`, because opened page does not know anything about `someExternalVariable`. So how to pass external data to evaluate function in [phantomjs-node](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variable is serializable you could do it this way

```
someExternalVariable = 'foo';
page.evaluate(function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
}, someExternalVariable ).then(function(html){
    console.log(html);
})
```

If it's not (say you want to pass a function with closure) I doubt there is a way to do it. [Docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html).

> Note: The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must
>   be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be
>   serialized via JSON, then it is fine.